# How do I compile a binary with a const string in debug and change it in release?

Tags: debugging, macros, release, nim-lang

I would like to create a binary that is storing some configuration data that will be supplied at compile time and built into the binary that I don't want present in the release versions.

In C I would do this like

```c
#ifdef DEBUG
#define LOOKUP_TABLE "{this:is:test:json}"
#else
#define LOOKUP_TABLE "{this:is:release:json}"
#endif
```

Below I can get it defined for runtime...but I dont want the debug string in there at all

```
#debug
when not defined(release):
  const LOOKUP_TABLE: string = "{this:is:test:json}"
#release
when defined(release):
  const LOOKUP_TABLE: string = "{this:is:release:json}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you already know about `when` and you are rather looking for a way to not insert the value of the lookup table directly into source code. Maybe you are looking for the [staticRead](https://nim-lang.org/docs/system.html#staticRead,string) macro?

```
const LOOKUP_TABLE =
    when defined(release):
        staticRead("release.json")
    else:
        staticRead("debug.json")

echo LOOKUP_TABLE
```

Comment: thank you this is exactly what i needed and a much cleaner solution than I was imagining

Answer (score 0):

`const` is a compile time constant, so it will only exist in your program if you directly reference it with runtime code, otherwise Nim will statically evaluate the operations and not include it.